# Mac OS X 10.6.8 App Store not working

Tags: macos, snow-leopard, mac-appstore

I recently reinstalled  Mac OS X on my iMac to Mac OS X 10.6.3 then updated to Mac OS X 10.6.8 and now I am trying to update to OS X El Capitan but when I go to the App Store to download, I click the "GET" button and nothing happens. Nothing also happens when I try to do this with any other apps.

Comment: Which specific iMac model do you have (aka are you sure it can run El Capitan)? Also, did you try to log out of the store and back in again?

Comment: The answers in http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/208292/cant-login-in-mac-app-store-or-icloud-login-loading-forever?rq=1 might give some clues as well

Comment: I am facing the same problem trying to upgrade my Sister's iMac from Snow Leopard (10.6.8) to El Capitan. The link in the above comment is unhelpful as it is problems someone is facing already running El Capitan. The problem here is even getting El Capitan in the first place. In my case, the iMac is fully capable of running Sierra (Early 2009 iMac), and El Capitan is just a stepping stone to Sierra.

Comment: Marked as dupe just to lead people to a new canonical answer for many variations on this theme.

Comment: @Tetsujin that duplicate doesn't seem to address this particular issue... for followers: I was able to get around this problem by manually going to "software update", install all available updates, reboot, repeat about 3x, and then my app store GET button started working like it should

Comment: @Tetsujin, this question is not a duplicate of linked question. This is about the App Store no longer working in 10.6.8 (for any download). That question is about a specific download in the App Store. There is a duplicate: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/300017/, but regretfully without answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a version of El Capitan specifically being kept available for any Mac that needs the stepping stone to Sierra, or that can run El Capitan but not Sierra.

It's on the App Store at https://itunes.apple.com/app/os-x-el-capitan/id1147835434?mt=12

You cannot use it to revert from Sierra to El Capitan, for that you need to already have El Capitan in your purchase history.

As far as I'm aware, but cannot test, you cannot use it to upgrade to Sierra if your machine could do it without the stepping stone.

[image]