# Unable to sign out of iCloud, sign in to App Store, or use iMessage. High Sierra

Tags: macos, icloud, messages, apple-id, apple-store

I am unable to sign in or out on iCloud or the App store. Whatever app I am using (Sys Prefs, App Store) loops endlessly. I can quit Prefs, but have to force quit the App Store. iMessage operates but all messages are marked as undelivered. Virtually all documents stored in iCloud drive do not appear in the Finder, but are available through the web (iCloud) interface. All of this works fine in my test account, so it's not a S/N issue, but switching everything to the test account is not an option.

I have deleted assorted caches and prefs. Enabled/Disabled iCloud Keychain, tried (unsuccessfully) signing out of iCloud while off line, and probably a few other things that I can't remember.

Mid-2012 15" MBP 16GB. 10.13.1

Comment: see https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/208292/cant-login-in-mac-app-store-or-icloud-login-loading-forever/216499#216499 or https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/105221/messages-wont-let-me-sign-in-to-imessage/205322#205322

Comment: Thanks. I have tried or attempted most of these (except serial number) without success.I am unable to sign out of iCloud, nothing that is stored in iCloud (Keychain, Docs folder,. etc) is accessible via the finder, although it is accessible via the web interface.

Comment: I am going to try deleting the Keychain entirely.

Answer (score 1):

Finally was able to get this sorted. It turns out that deleting the Keychain through Keychain Access prefs is insufficient. I needed to go to ~/Library/Keychains, open the folder with the Keychain, and drag the contents to the trash (or to a folder on the Desktop). Logging out and back in solved everything.