# Stuck at login in App Store

Tags: mac-appstore, macos, login

I've upgraded to El Capitain and since then I can't login to the App Store.
The App Store prompts me for my login details and once I try to sign in, it just shows a spinner for ever. I have to eventually force quit.

- The login details are correct (I've check on the web App Store and they work)
- I've tried deleting the cache for the App Store (no luck)
- No VPN / Anti-Virus / Firewall running
- I've check some other suggestions such as checking the serial number, and the number is in place.

I don't know if it gives a clue, but when I tried to run Tweetbot (bought through the App Store) it prompts me for my details saying "This App was purchased on another computer, please sign-in to continue using". This is not true, I'm using the same machine I bought the app with.

This is quite annoying since I have a bunch of updates (many security ones) which I can't download and some apps don't even work.

Any suggestions? Thank you.

Comment: Just an idea… try going to https://www.icloud.com/#settings & 'Sign out of all browsers' then try again. Otherwise you might be in for the chase I had with iCloud/FaceTime/iMessage - http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/105221/messages-wont-let-me-sign-in-to-imessage/205322#205322

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Grr - the store is having a rough week.

I would do these three things:

1. Make a new admin user account and log out of the broken "MAS account" to get a clean state.
2. Run the app store on the new user account. You don't need to sign in for security updates, so this will test that Apple's side of things is working and/or your core system is working.
3. If that doesn't work, open terminal and run these two exact commands:

   ```
   softwareupdate --reset-ignored

   softwareupdate --install --all
   ```

You can take a picture of that screen and then call AppleCare or open a web support ticket if you can't get that to work. They should cover that for free since it's security related as well as they generally support anyone's Apple ID that would be used to spend money on the store without charging them for that incident of support. The core updates should work even when your account or the Apple servers for authentication are overloaded. When that happens you get errors like you mentioned and Apple's support pages rarely log an error until everyone is locked out. (i.e. thousands of people could have problems and it's not a big issue when millions of accounts still work).

- http://apple.com/support/systemstatus

I use that "contact us" link from the system status page to initiate my support requests for cloud and Apple ID issues :-)