# Accessing App Store using USB wireless card instead of AirPort

Tags: macos, mac-appstore

I'm having trouble accessing my App Store account on my MacBook Air.

First of all, my AirPort chip was broken, so I bought a USB wireless card. Then my App Store account stopped working.

My question is: can I use my App Store account without having the card?

Comment: I don't believe the issue you are having is due to your USB wireless.  Can you clarify how exactly you are having trouble accessing the App Store?  On a side note, replacement [AirPort cards for the MBA](http://amzn.to/2wPRUj0) are super cheap and very easy to replace - probably around the same price as the USB wireless.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. You can have dozens of network connections and the App Store supports them all. You’ll want to troubleshoot the store process normally without worrying about network adapter.

Maybe:

- https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT203421 official troubleshooting MAS
- [Stuck at login in App Store](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/215793/stuck-at-login-in-app-store)