# WiFi Not staying connected after sleep-wake

Tags: network, wifi, sleep-wake, password, keychain

***Background***
I am having keychain issues since upgrading to El Capitan, Described below. Also working with Apple support since 2 weeks and i have no hope for a solution
[OS X El Capitan keychain login cannot be found to store](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/226248/os-x-el-capitan-keychain-login-cannot-be-found-to-store)

**Issue**
I close the lid on my computer and then when i open it it loses the connectivity to WiFi and i have to connect it every time

After connecting i get a message as below
[image]

Meaning that it can't save the password or something and then i am back to square one where after coming out of standby i'll have to reconnect again

***Question***
Is there any way to have my wifi stay connected without relying on Keychain. Meaning is keychain the only way for it to save my password or save my connection

Please let me know if more clarification is required

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue just resolved on it's own yesterday, it might be something Apple pushed but i do not see any app updates