# MacBook Pro trouble signing into App Store, iMessage and iCloud

Tags: macbook-pro, mac-appstore

New macbook and while trying to sign into the App Store, iMessage and iCloud it just loads for hours, correct email and password yet loading symbol appears and spins for hours. Any fixes??

Comment: see http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/105221/messages-wont-let-me-sign-in-to-imessage/205322#205322

Answer (score 1):

I believe it is a problem on Apple's side. Just give it a day or two and try again.

http://www.macrumors.com/2016/03/23/mac-users-facetime-imessage-login-issues/