# What files should be copied to manually migrate a user account?

Tags: macos, filesystem, user-account, system-settings, migration

The user account I normally use has something wrong with its native OS "Internet Accounts" configuration. It's corrupted or something. This causes login failures within native OS X apps such as "Messages", "Notes", "Contacts", "Calendar". I've tried deleting all temporary files, such as preferences files. Nothing has worked.

I want to create a fresh, new user account and copy over my preexisting user files for non-native applications so that my software licenses and software configurations are restored faithfully within this fresh account.

1. What folders/files will I need to copy?
2. Is there anything else I'll need to do, such as set permissions on those files?

Comment: If by user files, you mean everything in /Users/whatever - have you counted the number of files to consider? (in terminal ls -laR ~ | wc -l) - my user folders generally have about 600k files to consider. Part 1 is not an easy thing to generalize ...

Comment: Might be easier to fix the existing setup - see http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/105221/messages-wont-let-me-sign-in-to-imessage/205322#205322 for ideas

Answer (score 1):

Remove accounts.plist file from /Users/username/Library/Mail/V2/MailData/ as well as /Users/username/Library/Preferences/com.apple.internetaccounts.plist
Log out, then log back in.
Try it again.

Comment: Should be V3 for El Capitan, iirc.