# Apple Messages Not Working At All After Update

Tags: ios, data-synchronization, macos, messages, dropbox

I recently updated to OS 10.12.2 (16C67), all of my apps (most recently iTunes), and my phone to 10.2, and I'm having an issue with my Apple Messages app not syncing, and not being able to send or receive messages.

I was also getting various alerts that my phone was trying to access my messages (the map in the alert pointed directly to my house), and my Dropbox used to auto-download my pictures, and now it says it can't find any.

I don't know those issue are related or not, but the all started around the same time. For now, however, I want to focus on getting Messages up and running properly.

I have gone through the recommended process of disabling and re-enabling my Apple ID several times. I have quite and restarted both the app and my computer in-between disabling and re-enabling. I've also done the same with my phone, and even done a full restore.

The only next step I can think of is to either delete everything related to Messages and start from scratch, but I'd prefer not to lose my archived messages.

Does anyone have a less drastic recommendation?

Thanks!

ty

Comment: See if this helps. http://apple.stackexchange.com/a/205322/85275 I just had it happen again after a Time Machine restore & I was back up & running quickly.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out that the culprit was an iPad. I've never used it for Messages, so it never occurred to me to disable iMessage on it.

You have to disable it on **all** devices to get it to properly reset, even if you've never opened the app on one.

Thanks for the tips.

Answer (score 0):

To solve iMessage sync, you need to disable iMessage on your phone first. Then enable it and also enable "Text Message Forwarding" within Messages settings on iPhone. You can select your Mac there.